# FPS Cap Still Causes Flicker

Tags: java, animation, applet, flicker, japplet

I'm using an FPS cap which to set to 60 fps. I've tested it, and it's working. The problem is that it still causes screen flicker. My monitor is set to 60 fps. I don't know how it's still causing flicker. Here is my code:

```
package com.bgp.chucknorris;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.net.URL;

public class ChuckNorrisApplet extends Applet implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Thread thread = null;
    Image title;
    URL base;
    MediaTracker mt;
    String fps = "";

    public void init() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

        mt = new MediaTracker(this);
        base = getDocumentBase();
        title = getImage(base, "title.png");
        mt.addImage(title, 1);
        try {
            mt.waitForAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(title, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void start() {
        if (thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        thread = null;
    }

    public void run() {
        int frames = 0;

        double unprocessedSeconds = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double secondsPerTick = 1 / 60.0;
        int tickCount = 0;

        requestFocus();

        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            long passedTime = now - lastTime;
            lastTime = now;
            if (passedTime < 0)
                passedTime = 0;
            if (passedTime > 100000000)
                passedTime = 100000000;

            unprocessedSeconds += passedTime / 1000000000.0;

            boolean ticked = false;
            while (unprocessedSeconds > secondsPerTick) {
                unprocessedSeconds -= secondsPerTick;
                ticked = true;

                tickCount++;
                if (tickCount % 60 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(frames + " fps");
                    fps = Integer.toString(frames);
                    lastTime += 1000;
                    frames = 0;
                }
            }

            if (ticked) {
                repaint();
                frames++;
            } else {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) Why an `Applet` (as opposed to a `JApplet`)?  2) Why an applet as opposed to a frame?  3) Don't use `null` for an `ImageObserver` in paint when most components implement one.

Comment: Wow. Changing to a `JApplet` worked.

Comment: There are other changes that should be made now it is Swing.  Instead of `Thread`/`Runnable`/`sleep()`, implement a Swing `Timer`.   Move the `paint()` into the `paintComponent()` of a `JPanel`.  Load the image using `ImageIO` and drop the `MediaTracker`..  I added that first suggestion as an answer (with explanation).

Comment: Sure.  Don't sleep on the EDT.  That can be avoided using the Swing `Timer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why an `Applet` (as opposed to a `JApplet`)?  Note that Swing components are double buffered.